# Import data from Excel to SQL Server via Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, import

i found a few examples online on how to import excel into sql via vb. but can i do it via stored procedure?

```
Insert into SQLServerTable Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')
```

so like, can i pass in:

```
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
        'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 
        'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')
```

as a parameter to SQL Server SP? or how else can i protect myself from sql injections and other attacks?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an SSIS package and have it transfer from Excel to SQL Server (or flat file etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @bcpCommand varchar(2000), @dt varchar(15), @fn varchar(20), @fn1 varchar(30), @ty char(4) = '.csv', @path varchar(15) = 'C:\sive\'

SELECT @dt = convert(varchar,getdate(),112)

SELECT @fn = 'TblEnquiry_bcp'

SELECT @fn1 = @fn+'_'+@dt+@ty

SELECT @bcpCommand = 'ren '+ @path+@fn + @ty +' ' + @path + @fn1

SELECT @bcpCommand = 'ren '+ @path+@fn + @ty +' ' + @fn1

EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand

select @bcpCommand = 'bcp "SELECT hc.RegNo VehicleNo, convert(date,hv.DisplayDateTime,112) RunningDate,

       COUNT(1) AS NoofCountPlayed, hv.BoardTransID BoardTransId

       FROM Advertisementlog hv  WITH (NOLOCK)

       INNER JOIN VehiclesM hc WITH (NOLOCK) ON hv.BoardTransID=hc.RTONo

       WHERE convert(varchar(30),displaydatetime,112)>=convert(date,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0),112)

       AND convert(varchar(30),displaydatetime,112) <= convert(date,getdate(),112)

       AND hc.RTONo IS NOT NULL AND hc.RTONo <>''

       GROUP BY hc.RegNo, convert(date,hv.DisplayDateTime,112), hv.BoardTransID" queryout C:\Sive\TblEnquiry_bcp.csv -t, -c -T -SHABXC3NKSD -d WeddingVowsUAT'



EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand

select @bcpCommand = 'copy /b c:\sive\TblEnquiry_Header.csv+c:\sive\tblenquiry_bcp.csv c:\sive\test_bcp.csv'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

Comment: Even if your answer solves the problem of the OP you should include an explanation. Code-only answers are not well accepted here.